# How to install GNOME desktop on linux (CENTOS)

Tags: linux, centos, gnome

How to install GNOME desktop on linux (CENTOS).I would appreciate detailed steps as I am a linux newbie.

Comment: Is this really a suitable question for server fault? There must be ton of support for CentOS users online, including here http://www.centos.org/modules/newbb/

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo yum install gnome-desktop
```

Breakdown:

- **sudo** to gain administrative permissions (installation of package)
- **yum** is Redhat's package manager, it can perform various actions such as install, remove and update
- **install** is what you want yum to do, in this case it's quite clear
- **gnome-desktop** is the name of the package to install

Comment: Thanks; does centOS has the required libraries(sources) already bundled or do I need to download them.